# Can we use “paypal payment method” in magento for Indian shopping website?

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal

I am having a Indian shopping website which is set up in magento.
I just need to know weather we can use paypal as a payment method for purchases.
If yes, then how?
If no, then why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can, but you should display currency as a Dollar $ not INR.

Comment: Why should I use dollar as currency, when the payments are to be done in rupee,

Comment: If you want to need PayPal you will display price as the dollar, otherwise, you can't use PayPal. PayPal does not support INR because INDIAN RBI Rules, maybe in future they solve their issue.